# matrix multiplication with elements containing infinity

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, infinity

Say, we have `A=np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0]])`

and, `b=np.array([1, -inf, 1, -inf])`

How can I obtain this output: `A.dot(b)=[-inf, -inf, -inf, 3]`?

Comment: 0 * infinity is undefined, which is why you get `[nan, nan, nan, nan]`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi how can I define 0* infinity=0?

Answer (score 1):

0 * infinity is undefined, which is why you get `[nan, nan, nan, nan]` when you do `A.dot(b)`.

A dot product of a matrix and a vector is simply their elementwise product, summed over the second axis. So,

```
A=np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0]])
b=np.array([1, -np.inf, 1, -np.inf])

X = A * b
print(X)
```

This gives us:

```
array([[  0.,  nan,   1., -inf],
       [  1., -inf,   0.,  nan],
       [  0., -inf,   2.,  nan],
       [  1.,  nan,   2.,  nan]])
```

Now, we know that the `nan` values are the result of the multiplication of `0` with `np.inf`. So, we can replace them with `0`.

```
X[np.isnan(X)] = 0
print(X)
```

Output:

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   1., -inf],
       [  1., -inf,   0.,   0.],
       [  0., -inf,   2.,   0.],
       [  1.,   0.,   2.,   0.]])
```

And finally, sum this over the second axis

```
result = X.sum(axis=1)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
array([-inf, -inf, -inf,   3.])
```

As a single function:

```
def dotinf(A, b):
    X = A * b
    X[np.isnan(X)] = 0
    return X.sum(axis=1)

P=np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0]])
q=np.array([1, -np.inf, 1, -np.inf])
r = dotinf(P, q)
```